# How do I know if the results from my http request are complete and full?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

So, I'm using the github APIv3 to get some data for a project I'm doing. I have to be sure that the results from my request are tight cause it's for an article I'm writing on code smells.
I have to know which classes developers are messing with so my data needs to be perfect and verifiable.

I made this HTTP request to the github API to get the data. The problem is sometimes the data gathered is A, sometimes it is B. Is there a way I can be SURE the data gathered is the full and complete data that can be gathered from the API? (the errors in the console are always the same).

```
for (let i = 0; i < devInfo.length; i++) {
  let dev = devInfo[i];
  let project = dev.project;
  let name = dev.dev;
  let repo = reposData.find(e => e.repo == project);
  let maxDate = repo.maxDate;
  let url = `repos/${repo.owner}/${project}/commits`;
  console.log("Dev: " + name + "      Project: " + project);
  client.get(url, {
    until: maxDate,
    author: name
  }, function(
    err,
    status,
    body,
    headers
  ) {
    if (err != null) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (Array.isArray(body)) {
      body.forEach(commitInfo => {
        let date = new Date(commitInfo.commit.author.date);
        if (commitInfo.author != null) {
          client.get(`${url}/${commitInfo.sha}`, {}, function(
            err,
            status,
            body,
            headers
          ) {
            if (err != null) {
              console.log(err);
            }
            if (body != null || body != undefined) {
              if (Array.isArray(body.files)) {
                body.files.forEach(file => {
                  let fnArr = file.filename.split("/");
                  let javaClass = fnArr.find(e => e.match(/.java/));
                  if (validPojects.some(e => e == project)) {
                    if (javaClass != null) {
                      let classArr = javaClass.split(".");
                      let className = classArr[0];
                      fs.appendFileSync(
                        "filesMoved3.csv",
                        project +
                        "," +
                        name +
                        "," +
                        className +
                        "," +
                        date +
                        "\n"
                      );
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Unless there's a bug in the server, there's no reason why you should get an incomplete response.

Comment: `e.match(/.java/)` should probably be `e.match(/\.java/)` so you match `.` literally.

Comment: If there is a content-length header, you could check that the response is exactly that long.